# Averaging and plotting values across separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have four dataframes, each structured a so:

```
   index 1 2 3 4 5 6 . . . n
    Q1   # # # # #
    Q2   #
    Q3   #
    Q4   #
```

Both the Questions (`Q1`,`Q2`,..) and the number range `1`-`n` are the index for my dataframe

I want to take the average of every row of data which would be the average score per question

```
       index 1 2 3 4 5 6 . . . n average
        Q1   # # # # # #  avg_q1
        Q2   #            avg_q2
        Q3   #               .
        Q4   #               .
```

After I take the average for each row df on each, I want to make separate line graphs for each question on the the dfs and plot the data points if the number values (`Q#`) are the same. So some questions may have  a chart with 4 points, some with two. If possible, I would like to also have somewhere on the plot the average percent change from the first df to the last one where they have similar Q#.

Answer (score 1):

You asked many question in a question ^^

As a start you can have a look to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3))

df_mean = df.mean(axis=0)
for column in df.columns :
    df.plot(y=column)


print(df_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the average of each column or row with `df.mean()`
You can specify axis=0 or axis=1 acorfing to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html